# IPhone Login to Website with SSL

Tags: iphone, ios5, ssl

I have a problem login to website from an Iphone App. It is a https, so an SSL secured site. Unfortunately I get an error message when I try to log. And I don´t know what to do to fix this error.

**Here the Error Message:**

```
2012-08-20 13:38:56.490 Login_2[330:f803] IN GETFILELIST: (null)
2012-08-20 13:38:56.903 Login_2[330:f803] ERROR: (null)
2012-08-20 13:38:56.914 Login_2[330:f803] ERROR!: 
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo=0x6ab9ac0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.remote.sokratherm.de:80/?content=tableau&tableau=1, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.remote.sokratherm.de:80/?content=tableau&tableau=1, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSUnderlyingError=0x6abea00 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."}
```

**Here the Code:**

```
NSString *apiPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@/", hostServer, hostPort];

httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiPath]];
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:hostUser password:hostPass];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"index.php" parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

If you need some more Information please ask. 
I am pleased with any help.

Greetz.

Comment: Try on any software like 'HTTpClient' or 'Rest Client(firefox addon)'. Because this is looks like issue at server side. Either SSL certificate is expired or bad certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server `www.remote.sokratherm.de` doesn't appear to be running with SSL on port 80. Did you mean to specify that port? If not, remove the `:80` from your request URL.

Answer (score 1):

You should check these two methods:

```
[operation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:^BOOL(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace)
{
    //return YES or NO according to information received in 
    //objects *connection* and *protectionSpace*
}];
```

And this one:

```
[operation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:^BOOL(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace)
{
    **if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"YOURHOST"])**
    {
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"YOURUSER" password:@"YOURPASSWORD" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
}];
```